# Is there a way to register a repository base class with a spring boot auto configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have a base JPA repository class with some additional utility methods that we use in our projects. Following the [Spring Data JPA documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) we created the class and use the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in a configuration class as in the following example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = MyApplication.class,
    repositoryBaseClass = MyJpaRepositoryImpl.class)
public class SpringDataJpaMyRepositoryConfiguration {
}
```

We also set the *basePackageClasses* attribute so our repositories are found, as the configuration class is not in the application root package. Everything works as expected, so no problems so far.

Now we would like to create a spring boot starter to add the repository base class to our projects without further configuration, but we don't know how to do it. If we create an AutoConfiguration class with the *EnableJpaRepositories* annotation setting the *repositoryBaseClass* attribute, the automatic repository lookup strategy which looks for repositories under the class annotated with *@SpringBootApplication* doesn't work anymore.

And we can't use the *basePackageClasses* attribute as we don't know the main class or package of the project using the autoconfiguration.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe by redefining some bean in our autoconfiguration?

The ideal way would be something that allows to set the repository base class without having to define all the Spring Data JPA autoconfiguration again.

Comment: I am having the same issue and still looking for a solution. The answers provided by rdlopes and dan.jones unfortunately do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This question has driven me crazy at the time, so I thought I could help you on this.

Basically, the idea is to:

- Create a configuration class for your Jpa config
- Add @EntityScan and @EnableJpaRepositories referencing the same configuration class as the basePackageClass
- Import this configuration class in your autoconfiguration
- Create an annotation that you can then reuse where you need your Jpa config

In your example, you're using your Spring application class as your base for scannning.

I've put up a sample project to POC the main ideas at https://github.com/rdlopes/custom-jpa-demo

In the example, there's a project for the JPA entities/repositories exposing a JPA configuration:

```
   @Configuration
   @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = JpaConfiguration.class)
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = JpaConfiguration.class,
                          repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
   public class JpaConfiguration {

   }
```

Be careful with the common implementation for your repositories, you need to show a special signature:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>
        implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public String someCustomMethod(ID id) {
        return "Class for entity of id " + id + " is: " + getDomainClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

You can then create your auto configuration as such:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(CustomJpaRepositories.class)
@Import(JpaConfiguration.class)
public class JpaCustomAutoConfiguration {

}
```

Providing an annotation to keep things tidy and use it where you need JPA:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface CustomJpaRepositories {
}
```

Using your JPA classes will be as simple as having this annotation where you call your JPA repositories:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@CustomJpaRepositories
public class CustomJpaSampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomJpaSampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner dataInitializer(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return args -> {
            User user1 = new User();
            user1.setName("user 1");
            userRepository.save(user1);

            User user2 = new User();
            user2.setName("user 2");
            userRepository.save(user2);

            userRepository.findAll()
                          .forEach(user -> System.out.println(
                                  userRepository.someCustomMethod(user.getId())));
        };
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you getting passed the head scratching moments :-)

Comment: Thanks Rui, for the information and the sample project. However, this is not what we really need to solve. We don't provide entities and repositories in the library that provides the base repository class, that should be included into each project. But you can easily reproduce our scenario in your sample project, just move the _User_ entity and the _UserRepository_ from the _custom-jpa_ module to the _custom-jpa-demo_ module. Have you solved that situation by chance?

Comment: It is still unclear what you can and what you cannot change. For instance, you could imagine injecting your utilities into the custom repository by autowiring. You could also use a different @Configuration in your autoconfigure to reference a different set of beans and use composition pattern. The problem is that we don't have a clear architecture for your problem, I guess this is why the other answer is not fitting your requirements as well.

Comment: I'll be glad to answer any doubts you have or add more information. The other answer is almost on track, the only problem is that it doesn't solve the requirement of not needing any further configuration in the application. And that requirement is what's hard to solve I think.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I've pretty much rewritten my answer - I misunderstood the original question

It's not the nicest solution but the only way I can see this working is by using SpEL inside `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

This can then go in your auto-configuration and use `@ConditionalOnProperty` to only auto-configure if the base package property is set

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("repositories-base-packages")
public class BaseRepositoryAutoConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            repositoryBaseClass = MyJpaRepositoryImpl.class,
            basePackages = "${repositories-base-packages}"
    )
    public static class JpaRepositoriesConfig { }

}
```

Then make sure you have a `application.properties` or `application.yml` which defines `repositories-base-packages` inside your application.

Not sure how you'd declare multiple base packages, my SpEL knowledge is primitive so not sure if it would even be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't solve our problem at all. Your configuration sets the packages to look for classes with JPA annotations, but our problem relies on looking for Spring Data JPA repositories, which is not the same. Moreover I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require any further configuration to be performed, be it a configuration class or a property. Otherwise our current configuration class is simple enough.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misunderstood the question. I've updated the answer with another solution. This works, but not sure if it's possible to declare multiple base packages, someone with more SpEL would have to comment

Comment: Thanks again, but we are looking for a solution that doesn't require further configuration, not even a configuration property. We would like to set the repository base class and keep the default autoconfiguration as provided by the spring boot starter for spring data jpa, or at least provide the same autoconfiguration level.